# How to navigate to directly to the initial route when using TabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `TabNavigator` from `react-navigation`. It's working fine but I need to do a little trick.

When I navigate between `StackNavigator` routes, after changing tabs I need my route go directly in the initial route. So I need the route state to be reset.

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },


});

const AboutStack = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: AboutScreen },
});

TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    About: { screen: AboutStack },
  }
```

Let's say I am in the `Main` route from the `Home` tab and then I have navigated to `Profile` before switching to the `About` tab. When I go back to the `Home` tab I want my app directly to navigate to the `Main` route and clear history. Just like a reset.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe could use the `willFocus` listener in the Profile route of your HomeStack.

***Listener:***

```
class Profile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.didFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      () => { console.log('did focus') },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.didFocusListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return ( /* your render */ );
  }
}
```

And then in the case you are on `Main` and you are navigating to your `Profile` route. You should set a params in the navigation to say that the previous route is `Main`.

***Route parameters:*** `navigation.navigate('Profile', { previous_screen: 'Main' });`

So now in your `willFocus` listener:

- if the `previous_screen` param is set, it means that you don"t have to do anything.
- If not, means that you come from the other tab and that it will navigate to the wrong route. So you can either reset you're navigation route or just navigate to the 'Profile' route.

**NOTE:**

I didn't try this solution and maybe the transition animation is not going to be smooth. So tell me if it does the job well or not.